# .Net - Does a managed executable obtain a snapshot of GAC at start up?

Tags: .net, reflection, gac, .net-assembly

I somehow ran into the issue when I was working on an application that installs an assembly to GAC on demand (on click of a button), and tries to Assembly.Load it at the click of a next button or tries to invoke a method from that newly GAC-ed assembly, but fails. Problem and repro steps are below.

***Problem and Repro Steps:***
Create a new class library similar to the following named FooGreet.dll and strong name it. Let’s drag it to the assembly folder later.

```
namespace FooGreet
{
    public class Greeting
    {
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Create a console application to load the above class library, similar to the following code.

```
namespace FooGreetCaller
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to load assembly..");
            while (true)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "q" || input == "Q")
                    break;
                try
                {
                    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("FooGreet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=3f330bcf59df56c9");
                    Console.WriteLine("Assembly load success.");
                }
                catch (Exception eX)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(eX.Message + Environment.NewLine + eX.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. *Run the console applition:*  Run an instance of the console application. Try to load the FooGreet.dll, you will get an exception with “Could not load file or assembly….”, no matter how many times you load. Don’t close the console window.
2. *Install FooGreet.dll to GAC:*  Drag FooGreet.dll to GAC, on the same instance of the console application, try to load the FooGreet.dll again, you still get the same exception; which I call an anomaly because the FooGreet.dll is in the GAC, and the console application should have recognized it. Shouldn't it have?
3. *Run a second instance of the console application:*  Run a second instance of the console application. Try to load the FooGreet.dll, now the assembly is loaded fine.
4. *Uninstall FooGreet.dll from GAC:*  Go to GAC, uninstall FooGreet.dll. Try loading the FooGreet.dll again in the second instance of the console application. The assembly is loaded successfully. Ideally, Shouldn’t it have thrown an exception like “Could not load file or assembly….”?

***Question:***
Questions are at step 2 and 4. And from the happenings at step 2 and step 4, it looks like when an application loads, it takes a snapshot of the GAC (at least with the default AppDomain, I haven't tried creating and loading a new AppDomain). Is this true?

(In my app, as a workaround, I restart the application after I register the particular assembly to GAC with

```
System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish().GacInstall(targetAssemblyName);
```

I am on a WinForms app and I am doing the restart in the Form_Load which causes the Main Form to flash for a fraction of a second.. which I dont like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembly Binder actually uses caching. Any assembly which is requested in code, Assembly Binder follows its process to load the assembly. The result of assembly binding is cached by the Assembly Binder. When the same assembly is requested again, Assembly Binder looks in the cache and if the assembly was loaded correctly, reference to the loaded assembly is returned, if the assembly bind failed, exception is returned.

Another point to note that Binding Context is also used in caching. `Assembly.Load`, `Assembly.LoadFrom` and `Assembly.Load(byte[])`, these 3 methods uses 3 different binding contexts and caching is stored separately for each load type process. The recommended method however is `Assembly.Load`.

To verify all of this, you can enable fusion on your machine and see the binding results in [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The word "snapshot" isn't accurate, although it looks that way.  The assembly loader simply remembers all Assembly.Load/From() requests.  Including failed ones.  And makes sure that it very consistently returns the same outcome.  Including failed ones.  It is a strong anti DLL Hell counter measure.

The usage scenario is very strange so hard to come up with a workaround.  There is no way to reset that "I've seen it load before" status forcibly.  .NET 1.x however didn't do this so there's a app.exe.config setting you can use to restore 1.x behavior.  Use the [`<disableCachingBindingFailures>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms404312%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  But beware that this has a global effect.

To localize it to just this one assembly you could create an AppDomain, try to load the assembly into it and unload it again. You'll then know whether or not a load into your primary domain will fail.

Comment: if I am using an assembly's full name (as opposed to it's partial name), I am very particular to the CLR that load this assembly with this name, version, culture, publickeytoken. In case of LoadFrom() where assembly's partial name is supported, there might be DLL hell, if the assembly loader did not remember previous requests. I think I got it right. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What does this have to do with the file simply not being there?

Comment: Nothing. I was trying to understand the sentence _"It is a strong anti DLL Hell counter measure."_

Comment: +1 was mentioning the AppDomain details and "Dll Hell counter measure". I am marking jags as answer since he came first.